# Load custom JS file on admin login page

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, adminhtml

I am trying to load a custom JS script on the Magento admin panel login page (Magento version 1.7.0.2).

As per the accepted answer in [Issue adding javascript to magento admin page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42036/issue-adding-javascript-to-magento-admin-page), I added the following lines to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml`:

```
<adminhtml_index_login>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>dev/test.js</script></action>
  </reference>
</adminhtml_index_login>
```

Note: the above code was added inside the existing `<layout></layout>` tags.

I cleared the cache but it does not add the dev/test.js file to the HTML header.

What is wrong with my code and/or implementation method?

**Update 2018-03-06:**

Tried the following in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml` but the result is the same (file not added to login page):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
  ...
  <adminhtml_index_login>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>test.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
      <block type="adminhtml/template" name="content" template="login.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info" />
      </block>
    </block>
  </adminhtml_index_login>
  ...
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing it inside **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml** file, where you can find `adminhtml_index_login` layout update

**UPDATE**

My mistake... if you check **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml** you will see all head resources are loaded there, because of that the call through layout files don't do anything, as `head` block is not called / used

So, you'd add your js directly in that template

Comment: The result is still the same - the JS file isn't added to the login page. I cleared the cache after making the change also.

Comment: Are u using custom theme for adminhtml?

Comment: No custom theme for adminhtml, only a custom theme for the frontend.

Comment: Update your question witth the code changes you've tried in layout/main.xml file

Comment: Added main.xml code to question as requested

Comment: I've updated my answer... my mistake

Comment: That's a bummer - I would prefer not to update core templates in case they get updated by future patches and/or the custom code breaks the patching functionality. Is it possible to add custom text to the login page? Maybe we could load the JS file that way (in the body of the page).

Comment: Your only choice could be to create a custom theme for backoffice then... but the patch / upgrade problem will still be there

Comment: Apart from that, if you don't want to edit app/design files then the layout approach we were talking before would have the same problem